# How to adjust the size of a `FrameLabel` that consists of a picture or an object from MaTeX?

Tags: plotting, labeling, matex, frame

I want to plot a figure with $\LaTeX$ formulas as labels. A simple example looks like the following:

```
<<MaTeX`
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (MaTeX /@ {"x", "\\rm{sin}(x)"})]
```

However, the labels `sin(x)` and `x` are too small in the figure for me and I want larger ones. How can I adjust their sizes?

In another case if the label is a figure, like

```
fig = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True];
Export["test.pdf", fig];
lab = Import["test.pdf"] // First;
DeleteFile["test.pdf"];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {None, lab}]
```

Again, how do I adjust the label size?

Comment: You can set the font size for MaTeX, `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> MaTeX[{"x", "\\sin x"}, FontSize -> 18]]`. `\sin x` is better than using `\rm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, there are two options that will affect the size of labels; you can also adjust the size of the plot to have the labels appear larger.

```
<< MaTeX`
SetOptions[MaTeX, "FontSize" -> 14, "Magnification" -> 1.2];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (MaTeX /@ {"x", "\\rm{sin}(x)"}),
 ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]

For your second example just use `ImageSize` when creating the label.

```
fig = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 120];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, fig}]
```

Again, if your label is any image object you can use `Show` with a size option:

```
pic = (* some picture goes here *)
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, Show[pic, ImageSize -> Small]}]
```

[image]

Comment: What if the figure is the photo from my cellphones or any other source? I know that I can use ImageSize to control the label size in the wolfram system but I want to know how to deal with a general case.

Comment: @Jie see my edit